# Обработка строки в SQLite. Разложение строки на подстроки

Tags: sqlite

Есть таблица:
[image: Простая таблица]

Если таблица содержит список строк под два элемента, то запрос

```
*INSERT INTO partner_country_list(country_cod1, country_cod2) SELECT substr(ListOfCountry,1, pos-1) as country_cod1,  substr(ListOfCountry,pos+1) as country_cod2 FROM (SELECT *, instr(ListOfCountry,'#') as pos FROM partner_country);*
```

выдаёт результат:

```
partner_country_list        
id_LOF  country_cod1    country_cod2
1           AU                US
2           AU                DE
3           AT                AU
4           AT                AU
5           AU                CA
6           AU                CA
итд
```

Как доработать запрос, если в поле более двух элементов?

```
partner_country 
id_LOF  ListOfCountry
1       AU#US#WO
2       AU#DE#TW#US#WO
3       CA#EP#JP#US#WO
```

Comment: @PetSerAl Я восхищён! Спасибо. Запрос работает. Осталось дело за малым — разобраться, как это работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи можно воспользоваться рекурсивными [общими табличными выражениями](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html), поддержка которых была добавлена в [SQLite 3.8.3](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_3.html):

```
with t(id_LOF, Country, Rest) as (
    select
        id_LOF,
        null,
        ListOfCountry
    from partner_country
union all
    select id_LOF,
        case
            when instr(Rest, '#')=0 then Rest 
            else substr(Rest, 1, instr(Rest, '#')-1)
        end,
        case
            when instr(Rest, '#')=0 then null
            else substr(Rest, instr(Rest, '#')+1)
        end
    from t
    where Rest is not null
    order by id_LOF
)
select
    id_LOF,
    Country
from t
where Country is not null
```

Идея состоит в том, что сначала мы помещаем `ListOfCountry` в поле `Rest` и затем на каждом шаге отделяем одну запись из `Rest`, а остаток оставляем для дальнейшей обработки.